# Convert arbitrary Prolog term to one structurally equivalent with all variables

Tags: prolog, pattern-matching

Wondering how to do this in SWIProlog, e.g., convert term
    [elvis, [was, dead]]

into

```
[A, [B, C]]
```

How to do this with arbitrary data structures?

For example, convert term

```
ty(simple, _)
```

into

```
ty(A, _)
```

and convert term
    ty(ty(complex, _), _)

into

```
ty(ty(A, ), _)
```

Comment: What do you expect `G` to be in `ty(T,G)` for: `T = [a|non_list]` `T = [[]]`? It seems you do not want to generalize the `[]` away, but this is quite tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples suggest that you want a term *template* constructed from a term. As a bound term can be depicted as a tree, the construction of the term template can be seen as replacing the bound tree leaves with fresh variables. Therefore, a solution is to traverse the tree and do the necessary transformation to its leaves. This can be accomplished by using the standard `functor/3` and `=../2` predicates. For example:

```
% template(@term, -term)

template(Term, Template) :-
    (   var(Term) ->
        true
    ;   Term = [_| _] ->
        template_arguments(Term, Template)
    ;   functor(Term, Functor, Arity),
        functor(Template, Functor, Arity),
        Term =.. [Functor| Arguments],
        Template =.. [Functor| TemplateArguments],
        template_arguments(Arguments, TemplateArguments)
    ).

template_arguments([], []).
template_arguments([Argument| Arguments], [TemplateArgument| TemplateArguments]) :-
    (   compound(Argument) ->
        template(Argument, TemplateArgument)
    ;   % variables and atomic terms
        true
    ),
    template(Arguments, TemplateArguments).
```

Some queries:

```
?- template(ty(ty(complex, _), _), Template).
Template = ty(ty(_G1211, _G1212), _G1191).

?- template([elvis, [was, dead]], Template).
Template = [_G1196, [_G1202, _G1205]].

?- template([elvis, [was, dead]| _], Template).
Template = [_G1199, [_G1205, _G1208]|_G1117].
```

Maybe you can adapt this solution to solve your problem?

Comment: Sometimes the 2nd argument shares variables with the first and sometimes not.

Comment: The special case for `[_|_]` seems to introduce the problems. Similar problem in `template_arguments/2`

Comment: Yes thanks very much, I had a feeling the goal was not far from the reach of some standard built-ins, but I was frustrated by the action of `=@=/2` which does what I wanted in a way, but only for terms instantiated by variables.  At least I'm glad I did not miss some incredibly easy solution or library function, as this solution seems somewhat involved and has to completely decompose the term.